# Matplotlib adding grid lines inside the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid, astropy, wcs

When I make `matpoltlib` images, I provide `Astropy WCS` object as the projection. This make makes grid lines as shown below.

[image]

However, when I make images for the entire visible horizon I get something like the below
[image]

The problem in the above image is that, since the grid lines do not intersect the figure axis, the grid values do not get plotted. I was wondering if there is a way to show the grid values inside the figure (something like what gets done in a `mollweide` projection)

EDIT 1
The below is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
hdu = fits.open("image.fits")
wcs = WCS(hdu[0].header,naxis=2)
plt.subplot(111,projection=wcs)
plt.imshow(hdu[0].data[0,0,:,:],origin="lower") 
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='mollweide') did you try this

Comment: It would help if you share your code

Comment: @nithin I have included my code. Also, I do not want a mollweide projection. I just want to retain the image in the same projection but have the grid values shown inside the image (like what happens in mollweide).

Comment: can you upload the image which you use for image.fits , is it the first image?